# Eigen matrix in header file: unknown type name

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm getting a weird error when trying to declare an Eigen Sparse Matrix in a header file.

The header file is just:

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

Eigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double> > sp_eye(2,2);
sp_eye.coeffRef(0,0) = std::complex<double>(1,0);
sp_eye.coeffRef(1,1) = std::complex<double>(1,0);
sp_eye.makeCompressed();
```

When including this header and compiling:

I get "error: unknown type name 'sp_eye'", on line 2 of the snippet, even though I defined it in the previous line. The code snippet works fine if I include it in my main() function instead, for some reason... but I don't want it in my main program.

To test to see if it was picking up the declaration, I tried

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

Eigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double> > sp_eye;
Eigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double> > sp_eye(2,2);
sp_eye.coeffRef(0,0) = std::complex<double>(1,0);
sp_eye.coeffRef(1,1) = std::complex<double>(1,0);
sp_eye.makeCompressed();
```

and I got a redefinition error, confirming that the compiler knew about the declaration.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Where in the header file are you putting this snippet?  In a function?  In a constructor?

Comment: Can you round it out to a full fledged [mcve]?

Comment: The snippet is just a global definition in the header file, it doesn't live in anything else. I've edited the header code to reflect that. Merely including the header file in an empty .cpp file gives the error. However, writing those 4 lines of code defining sp_eye directly in the main() function of a .cpp file makes it work fine.

Comment: `sp_eye.coeffRef(0,0) = std::complex<double>(1,0);` is a *starement*. Statements must appear inside *functions*. They cannot appear at the top level of a source file. If you don't want them in `main`, use some other function.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm but I've looked at the documentation and it seems the only way to insert elements in order to construct a sparse matrix is mat.coeffRef() or mat.insert(). Is there any trick I can use in such cases in order to be able to globally define a matrix? I would be able to do such a thing with mathematical constants, e.g. const double pi = 3.14, and I want  these matrices to have the same status as such a constant

Comment: Ask the author of the matrix class to provide an appropriate constructor.